# Number of combinations where the sum of values must be the same

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My question is as follows: let there be $n$ different numbers $a_i$ in a set $A$, where each $a_i$ is a number between 0 and 1. How many different sets of values can I have that fulfill the condition $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=1$$ if the values of each $a_i$ may take on any of $k$ different values in the domain [0,1]? Does there exist a general formula to calculate this quantity? I have tried looking at formulas for numbers of combinations but run into trouble when trying to include the sum constraint.

(e.g. if allowed values of $a_i$ are $0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1$, then $k=5$).

Apologies in advance if I have used mathematical vocabulary inappropriately. Any advice on this matter would be much appreciated.

EDIT: values may be repeated

EDIT 2: Order does matter, e.g. {0.5, 0.5, 0} is distinct from {0.5,0,0.5}

Comment: In your example, suppose that $n=3$ and $k=5$. Is $0.5+0.5+0$ to be considered a different solution from $0.5+0+0>5$?

Comment: In your second expression how is 0.5 > 5 ?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant $0.5+0+0.5$. In other words, does order matter? The intended $0.5$ turned into $0>5$, through the magic of the shift key.

Comment: Ah yes, good question. Order does matter.

Comment: If you were looking for integer values for  $a_i$, then the concept of "Integer Partitioning" would apply. However with  $a_i$<1, I don't think there would be a closed form for the different number of ways.

Comment: You are asking about special compositions, not partitions, which is good, compositions are generally  easier. The natural approach is via generating functions. But the result may not be very attractive, it is closely related to the somewhat messy problem of the number of ways to get a certain sum when tossing $n$ dice.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Ross Millikan pointed out below that my question is equivalent to asking about integers because I am only allowing values of $a_i$ to be multiples of $1/x$ where $x$ is some integer. Therefore, I can multiply all $a_i$ by $x$ to make it an integer problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lots of sets the values must be rational (maybe times one irrational).  In your example, it would be equivalent to ask about subsets of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ that sum to $4$.  In your case $4$ can be achieved $5$ ways:  $1+1+1+1,1+1+2,1+3,2+2,4$.  If you allow different orders it becomes $8$.  If you allow $0$ there are infinitely many, as you can have as many zeros as you like.  Not allowing $0$ these are the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$.  There are $2^{n-1}$ of them, which you can see by a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument.  Put $n$ stars in a row.  There are $n-1$ places between them were you can choose to put a bar or not.  Each set of bars gives a composition.

Comment: (1) yes, 0 is allowed. (2) values may be repeated. Would this change what you said above?